# continue even on error after informing user

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

Hi I am processing lots of files and have a try except statement.

If for any reason, I dont have access to file, i would just like to inform the user using except statement...but once user is informed, i would like to keep on processing other files . The "pass" or "continue" is not working. How do i do that ?

```
 try:
      process long list of files  
 except: 
       (if any error occurred with any file, just inform user on console)
       and once user has been informed, resume processing of other files in the 
   list - this one is not working
```

how do i do that ?

Comment: What do you mean "the pass or continue is not working"? What is happening?

Comment: You have the answer, try except blocks. your long list of files should be looping "outside" a try except block, and just do your exception condition inside the loop so it runs on a file by file basis.

Comment: Your try and except need to be in the process of going through the files. Otherwise if there is an error, it won't resume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for file in files:
    try:
        process file  
    except:  
        print("Something wrong happens during processing the file '{}' ...".format(file))
```

(supposing `files` is a list of file names).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look as the pseudo-code above:

```
for file in files:
    try:
        process file
    except:
        Inform a user and do any logging, notification you want.
        Make sure that this code will not thew exception itself and pass or continue looping
```

There may be other strategies as for example caching or infinite `while` loop if you want to have several retries for processing file(-s).